# Automatic deployment to Restcomm

Tags: github, jenkins, restcomm

I'm setting up a Restcomm instance and I would like to integrate it with Jenkins, so each time we have a PR in github in a specific branch, Jenkins will deploy the RVD App to the Restcomm instance.

I have access to the RVD Workspace from Jenkins, so I guess I could have something like:

- Developer create/update her RVD app in local.
- She copies the APP from her workspace to a github repo and creates the PR.
- Jenkins updates the remote RVD workspace copying/updating the new files / app.

I guess this would be work but I don't like to copy files from one workspace to another one because of inconsistencies and so on.

I would prefer something like:

- Developer updates the APP source in github and creates a PR.
- Jenkins packages the app (zip?) and invokes a Restcomm API to deploy it / update it.

Is it possible? Any documentation about that API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have an open issue for that (providing an API) at https://github.com/RestComm/Restcomm-Connect/issues/947. Would you be interested in contributing to move it forward faster ?

Comment: Thanks @jeand. I'm currently working in other contribution.. but I will take a look to this one once I've finished the actual one. May I use the workspace copy/paste strategy for deploy/modify the apps or is there any drawback to do that?

Comment: @AntónR.Yuste yes that should work. We may need to think of versionning apps so that if the RVD is processing traffic, you don't have issues. Basically existing traffic stays with version N of the app and new traffic go to version N+1. Can you create an issue in github for that or add it to the existing issue ?

Comment: Here it's is https://github.com/RestComm/Restcomm-Connect/issues/1024 .  Any prize for the issue 1K? :-)